# ClassNotFoundException: previously working Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I had a working android project but needed to start from scratch. I copied all my source files and layout files over. There are no compilation errors but when I try to run, I get the following error.

```
11-27 17:21:56.793: E/AndroidRuntime(1450): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{projects.mobile.mapappproject/projects.mobile.mapappproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "projects.mobile.mapappproject.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/projects.mobile.mapappproject-1.apk
```

I am running eclipse juno and trying to run on Android 4.2. Thanks !

Comment: I would first try simple approach i.e. rgiht click and refresh the project (to sync the files from file system) and then perform a clean build and make sure its really building (ensure the .class files are generated in the target folder) as some later introduced class path issues stop making build of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried this. class files are being generated, still no dice..

Comment: SAME ISSUE, note that Im using git, its must be problem with eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than doing copy paste try following

1.Create an android application project

2.Delete the files which was created Eg.MainActivity and layout.

2.Right click on project name and click import ,then from File system.Go to your project directory to import the source from there

3.select that, then finish.

4.Clean and build then run

Answer (score 2):

Try these

1. Add the Activity to AndroidManifest.xml
2. Is there a difference in your folder names ? For example projects.mobile.mapappproject-1 or projects.mobile.mapappproject !

Comment: Please review  your answer. Next time be neat in your response. Avoid being shabby on responses.

Answer (score 1):

> I copied all my source files and layout files over.

It looks like you forgot to copy over the entries that existed in AndroidManifest.xml, however.  Each `Activity` has an entry there and that entry is required for the framework to find and launch the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I found out that a library reference path wasn't right. After I fixed that everything worked fine.
You can check this at Right-click on your project => Properties => Android -> (Library)

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the record in case I can help someone :*
I had a project that somehow didnt work after importing it from git. I solved this by giving the name of the activity explicitly.

**example:**
before:
`<activity android:name=".Main"  [...] />` (relative) 
after: `<activity android:name="com.example.package.Main" [...] />` (absolute)

This may also occur if you change the manifest package and keep your relative reference (which I think is default).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following 2 steps fixed the problem

a. Setting compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion to the same SDK version in build.gradle.

b. I was missing a dot in application class name in AndroidManifest.xml (Ex. android:name=".ui.ApplicationLoader")